# Android Studio: Error: Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord$Op

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

My gradle app.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.prutheus.se"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
}
```

When I want to Run my app in debugger, I get an Error:

```
Error: Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord$Op
```

I have read that it could has something todo with the implementation of `com.google.android.gms` stuff, but I do not know how to fix that?

Comment: did you try to implement support library in app level gradle? android.support.v4

Answer (score 0):

Added `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'` looks confusing-old.

You're using updated `SupportLibrary -> 28` but the `play-services` seems old.

In your root `build.gradle` add:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1' // and use the updated version
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0' // add this
    ..
    .
```

Also make sure about the repositories:

> Ensure that your top-level `build.gradle` contains a reference to the
>   `google()` repo or to `maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }`.

Read [**`Setup Google Play Services`**](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup).

Answer (score 0):

```
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2"
```

> This is the Soultion :

Go to Build Gradle App And Do this

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```